# How to go from a "polymorphic data-type a" to an instance of the Show class (without using "deriving Show")

Tags: haskell

Beneath this text, you can see some code for creating Arukone puzzles.
But there is a problem: the polymorphic data-type `Puzzle a` represents an Arukone puzzle with the labels of the type `a`.

But I would like to have a puzzle-type with the instance of Show class (without using `deriving Show`.) 
The show function would be enough, showsPrec isn't necessary.

So do you know how this works? I want to define Show for all the types `a` which are an instance of the following `ToChar` class?

```
class ToChar a where
 toChar :: a -> Char

instance ToChar Char where
 toChar = id

instance ToChar Int where
 toChar = head . show
```

**Code :**

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

data Size  = Size Int Int deriving (Eq, Show)
data Pos   = Pos  Int Int deriving (Eq, Show)
data Link l = Link l Pos Pos
data Puzzle l = Puzzle Size [Link l]

assign :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
assign 0 v (_:vs) = v:vs
assign n v (v’:vs) = v’: assign (n - 1) v vs

assign2 :: Int -> Int -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
assign2 r c v vs = assign r (assign c v (vs !! r)) vs

assignPos :: Pos -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
assignPos (Pos r c) = assign2 (r-1) (c-1)

tabulate :: Int -> (Int -> a) -> [a]
tabulate 0 _ = []
tabulate i f = f 0 : tabulate (i - 1) (f . (+1))

tabulate2 :: Int -> Int -> (Int -> Int -> a) -> [[a]]
tabulate2 b h f = tabulate h (\r -> tabulate b (\c -> f r c))

tabulatePos :: Size -> (Pos -> a) -> [[a]]
tabulatePos (Size h b) f = tabulate2 b h (\r c -> f (Pos (r +1) (c + 1)))

showPuzzle :: Puzzle a -> [[Maybe a]]
showPuzzle (Puzzle sz links) = tabulatePos sz findPosMaybe
  where findPosMaybe pos =  -- edit: findPosMaybe needs to be further left than the next line
          listToMaybe [l | Link l pos1 pos2 <- links, pos1 == pos || pos2 == pos]
```

**Solutions and Input**

```
*Main> show (Puzzle (Size 2 3) [Link 1 (Pos 1 1) (Pos 1 3), Link 2 (Pos 2 1) (Pos 2 3)])

"1 1\n2 2"


*Main> show (Puzzel (Size 5 5) [Link ’a’ (Pos 3 1) (Pos 4 3), Link ’b’ (Pos 5 1) (Pos 1 5), Link ’c’ (Pos 2 5) (Pos 5 5), Link ’d’ (Pos 4 1) (Pos 2 2)])

"    b\n d  c\na    \nd a  \nb   c"          <-- result -- remarks the spaces
```

*putStrLn of last example*

```
    b
 d  c
a 
d a 
b   c
```

All help is welcome.

Comment: Note I've edited your code for `showPuzzle` so that it compiles OK - a continuation line needs to be indented further.

Comment: Could you have a look at your second example? - I think you meant it to be a different one from the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's use the `ToChar` class to turn the Maybe elements into spaces or values:

```
maybeToString :: ToChar a => Maybe a -> String
maybeToString Nothing = " "
maybeToString (Just x) = toChar x : ""
```

Now we can make the Show instance:

```
instance ToChar a => Show (Puzzle a) where
  show = unlines . map (concatMap maybeToString) . showPuzzle
```

It's not clear to me whether you wanted padding or not, so you could alter your maybeToString to say `"  "` and `toChar x : " "` if you want more space.

With the definitions above we get:

```
*Main> show (Puzzle (Size 2 3) [Link (1 :: Int) (Pos 1 1) (Pos 1 3), Link 2 (Pos 2 1) (Pos 2 3)]) 
"1 1\n2 2\n"
*Main> putStrLn $ show (Puzzle (Size 2 3) [Link (1 :: Int) (Pos 1 1) (Pos 1 3), Link 2 (Pos 2 1) (Pos 2 3)]) 
1 1
2 2
```

Example 2:

```
*Main> show (Puzzle (Size 5 5) [Link 'a' (Pos 3 1) (Pos 4 3), Link 'b' (Pos 5 1) (Pos 1 5), Link 'c' (Pos 2 5) (Pos 5 5), Link 'd' (Pos 4 1) (Pos 2 2)])
"    b\n d  c\na    \nd a  \nb   c\n"
*Main> putStr it
    b
 d  c
a    
d a  
b   c
```

Comment: Hey, thanks,
small question, I saw that I had made a mistake with the second example. and changed this.

can you solve this too? so that Link 1 also be Link 'a' ?

Comment: @DieterVerbeemen Yup - see edit - this works according to your example above. Is this as you wanted?

Comment: @DerpDerpington Hi. You unaccepted my answer: is there something you'd like changed?

Comment: answer was perfect, but was testing for deleting the question, sorry for that :)